# Cypress disabled button is somehow clicked anyway without waiting

Tags: cypress

This is not how I would expect cypress to behave:
I have a button which is only enabled when to checkboxes are checked in the table below.
Before the checking of the 2 rows, the button is greyed out with:

```js
button[data-e2e-button][disabled=true]
```

Now cypress checks the 2 rows and the button becomes enabled. i.e. the "[disabled=true]" disappears. My code looks like this:

Non Working Code:

```js
cy.contains(`[data-e2e-button]`, buttonLabel, BUTTON_OPTS).should('not.be.disabled').should('be.visible').click...
```

When it clicks on this element, it seems like it did not wait until the button is enabled.

Only if I have a separate wait for the disabled=true to disappear it works:

Working Code:

```js
cy.contains('[data-e2e-button][aria-disabled="true"]', buttonLabel, BUTTON_OPTS).should('not.exist');
cy.contains(`[data-e2e-button]`, buttonLabel, BUTTON_OPTS).should('not.be.disabled').should('be.visible').click...
```

This seems kind of ugly to me, as it ensures twice for disabled to disappear.

Here is the html code:
ENABLED:

```html
<span role="tooltip">
<a class="MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-dense MuiMenuItem-gutters MuiButtonBase-root css-brjsa3" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span>
<span class="MuiBox-root css-1jjwf1f">Two Checkbox button</span>
</span>
<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-w0pj6f"></span>
</a>
</span>
```

DISABLED

```html
<span role="tooltip">
<a class="MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-dense Mui-disabled MuiMenuItem-gutters MuiButtonBase-root Mui-disabled css-brjsa3" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true" role="menuitem"><span>
<span class="MuiBox-root css-1jjwf1f">Two Checkbox button</span>
</span></a></span>
```

Comment: Please add the html of your button, with enabled and disabled state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your attribute is `aria-disabled="true"` as shown here

```html
<a class="MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-dense Mui-disabled MuiMenuItem-gutters MuiButtonBase-root Mui-disabled css-brjsa3" 
  tabindex="-1" 
  aria-disabled="true"                 // this is the attribute being checked
  role="menuitem">
  <span>
    <span class="MuiBox-root css-1jjwf1f">Two Checkbox button</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

then `.should('be.disabled')` and `.should('not.be.disabled')` do not work with that attribute.

They would only work with attribute `disabled="true"` which does not seem to be present.

It explains why this works

```js
cy.contains('[data-e2e-button][aria-disabled="true"]', buttonLabel, BUTTON_OPTS).should('not.exist');
cy.contains(`[data-e2e-button]`, buttonLabel, BUTTON_OPTS).should('not.be.disabled').should('be.visible').click...
```

because in the first line does check that attribute.

Try either of these

```js
cy.contains(`[data-e2e-button]`, buttonLabel, BUTTON_OPTS)
  .should('not.have.attr', 'aria-disabled')
  .click()
```

or

```js
cy.contains(`[data-e2e-button]`, buttonLabel, BUTTON_OPTS)
  .should('have.attr', 'aria-disabled', 'false')
  .click()
```

Comment: This is a good solution. It did work in that particular situation. Failed then in another as the code I use is a generic button-cypress element. Thanks in any case!

Answer (score 1):

Be careful when using negative assertions, they are often less reliable. Instead of using `.should('not.be.disabled')` before clicking the element, make sure the element is disabled before meeting the enabled condition.

```js
cy.contains(`[data-e2e-button]`, buttonLabel, BUTTON_OPTS)
  .should('be.visible')
  .and('be.disabled')
// actions to meet enabled condition
cy.contains(`[data-e2e-button]`, buttonLabel, BUTTON_OPTS)
  .should('be.visible')
  .and('be.enabled')
  // now we know for sure the button is enabled and click on it
  .click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. You can come up with a different selector as well, if this doesn't work, the idea remains the same.

```js
cy.get('a.MuiMenuItem-root').should('exist').and('be.disabled')
//code to click the checkboxes
cy.get('a.MuiMenuItem-root').should('exist').and('be.enabled').click()
```

In case `cy.get()` doesn't work, you can use contains with selector and button label, something like:

```js
cy.contains('a', 'button label').should('exist').and('be.disabled')
//code to click the checkboxes
cy.contains('a', 'button label').should('exist').and('be.enabled').click()
```